# Excel IF statement from drop down menu

Tags: excel, if-statement, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create an IF statement from a drop down menu where I have made the options Yes or No.

I have gone for: `=IF(B2=''Yes'',D5,0)`. This is giving me an error.

However when I try: `=IF(B2=Yes,D5,0)` it says I have used the wrong data type. Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: It seems (based on the formula posted) that you have enclosed `Yes` in two single quotes (`''Yes''`) rather than double quotes (`"Yes"`). Have you tried double quotes to match the text string?

Answer (score 0):

Since this was [cross-posted on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/936910/excel-if-statement-from-drop-down-menu-gives-error-wrong-data-type), I'm posting as an answer to "close out" this question:

It seems (based on the formula posted) that you have enclosed `Yes` in two single quotes (`''Yes''`) rather than double quotes (`"Yes"`). Excel uses double quotes for matching text strings, so change your formula to `=IF(B2="Yes", D5, 0)`.